# Homemade methods for interfacing a Servo with LEGO bricks

Tags: building, technic, compatibility, electronics

I'm looking for non-destructive way to structurally attach a standard servo with LEGO bricks.  I'm interested in answers for either Large, Medium or Small size servos.

I'm using LEGO Mindstorm/Technic bricks to prototype all kind of robotic projects and I often use non-LEGO parts for the electronics (e.g. Arduino, Servos, LEDs, ...).  I'm always trying to find better ways to integrate those non-LEGO parts without damaging the LEGO bricks.

I'm aware that there are some commercial adaptors available on the market but I'm interested in creative homemade solutions (low-cost to no-cost).

For example: here is one way to attach a medium size servo to a LEGO Technic beam:

[image: Servo attached to LEGO Technic beam]

Comment: At first I thought you were speaking of the electr(on)ic part of things, but now I think you may rather be after the physical assembly to LEGO parts - right?

Comment: @Joubarc Yes I'm talking about the physically attaching servos and LEGO bricks together. I'll clarify and add a image to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best solution is to create custom LEGO-compatible bricks that your servos (or other parts) fit into. This can be done by:

- modding existing bricks with knives, glue and other tools
- building bricks from other material ([wooden LEGO](http://www.instructables.com/id/Wooden-Legos/), formed with [Fimo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fimo)/[Sculpey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sculpey)...)
- building bricks with a 3D-printer (for instance see the [LEGO category on thingiverse](http://www.thingiverse.com/tag%3aLEGO)). There are online services to print your designs if you don't have a 3D printer (yet ;-)

Each strategy is worth another question here at bricks.SE.

Comment: To add to this answer, I would also suggest looking at [The Free Universal Construction Set](http://fffff.at/free-universal-construction-kit/). While they don't provide anything for integrating legos and servos specifically, there's a lot of examples of how to integrate Legos with non Legos components (some of which might make integrating a servo easier.)

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your rigidity requirements, I've found [double-sided tape](https://www.google.com/search?q=doublesided%20tape&hl=en&tbo=d&tbm=isch&sa=X&biw=1264&bih=851&sei=x1uZUK97qOXRAYbcgegF) to work well.

It's cheap and found in many general goods store. The servo itself can be taped and supported on all four sides and/or the bottom to many types of lego brick surfaces.

You can also use double-side tape to mount a lego surface to a servo control horn. That provides nearly infinite mounting flexibility. However, the control horn attachment will not be very rigid or support a lot of weight without an additional structures to support whatever is actually moving.

When finished, you can just peel the tape off.  (...which is sometimes easier said than done.)